# What is the easiest way to get current users data from Firestore?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I am trying to get the information of the current user of my Angular app from Firebase but I can't figure out what's the easiest way to get the current user and get his information from Firestore by searching on his uid.

This is my authService:

```
export class AuthService {
  private auth;
  private db;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.auth = getAuth();
    this.db = getFirestore();
    
    onAuthStateChanged(this.auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        router.navigate(['home']);
      } else {
        router.navigate(['login']);
      }
    });
  }

  getCurrentUser() {
    const currentUser = this.auth.currentUser;
    if (currentUser) {
      return currentUser;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  getCurrentUserDetails() {
    onSnapshot(doc(this.db, 'users', 'uid_from_current_user'), (doc) => {
      console.log(doc.data());
    });
  }
}
```

And my component:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private userService: UserService, private router: Router) { 
    this.userService.getCurrentUserDetails();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void { }


  signOut() {
    this.authService.signOut();
  }
}
```

What is the best way to get the current users uid now and send it to the getCurrentUserDetails() function? Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you consider calling `getCurrentUser().uid` inside `getCurrentUserDetails`?

Comment: Yes, but the getCurrentUser() always returns null in my constructor or ngOnInit(). Any idea why this happens?

Comment: `auth.currentUser` is automatically restored by Firebase when the page/app reloads, but that requires a call to the server and thus happens asynchronously. Once the user is restored your `onAuthStateChanged` handler will be called with that user, which would be a great place to then load the details of the user.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen How do you get the details from your service to your component then?